# How to get the correct mouse position on mouse move over element?

Tags: javascript, gsap

I'm working on a little thing where an image will follow the mouse once hover on its (in this case) parent element. Could be whatever element. When testing, it works on the first `data-tail-list`, but when hover on second `data-tail-list` or third or however many i choose to have in my markup, the image that follows the cursor gets an offset, which increases depending on how far from the browsers top the current hovered `data-tail-list` is. What am i doing wrong here?

Markup:

```
        <div class="list w-full h-16 bg-white mb-8" data-tail-list>
          <div class="absolute pointer-events-none w-64 h-96 max-w-full opacity-0 inset-0" data-tail-wrap>
            <div class="absolute w-full h-full inset-0" data-tail-item>
              <img src="./dist/img/test1.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list w-full h-16 bg-white mb-8" data-tail-list>
          <div class="absolute pointer-events-none w-64 h-96 max-w-full opacity-0 inset-0" data-tail-wrap>
            <div class="absolute w-full h-full inset-0" data-tail-item>
              <img src="./dist/img/test2.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
import gsap from 'gsap'

export default class Tail {
  constructor() {

    const lists = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-tail-list]')]

    lists.forEach((el) => {
      el.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.onEnter)
      el.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.onLeave)
      el.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMove)
    })
  }

  onEnter(e) {
    const el = e.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('[data-tail-wrap]')
    gsap.to(el, {
      opacity: 1
    })
  }

  onMove(e) {
    const el = e.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('[data-tail-item]')
    gsap.to(el,{
      x:e.clientX,
      y:e.pageY - e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect().top - e.currentTarget.querySelector('[data-tail-wrap]').offsetHeight/2
    })
  }

  onLeave(e) {
    const el = e.currentTarget.querySelector('[data-tail-wrap]')
    gsap.to(el, {
      opacity: 0
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: you are using a wrong method. you have to take the starting position of the mouse and always recalculate the delta x,y from this initial position. then apply this delta on the element to move

Comment: @MisterJojo Ok, do you mind providing some code?

Comment: @MisterJojo Would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Math on comments :

> Ok, do you mind providing some code?

> Would really appreciate it!

Since you insist...

Here is only a simple example of moving a Dom element based on the delta X and Y of the mouse movement reported on the moved element.

```js
const myDiv     = document.querySelector('#my-div');
      myDiv.mov = { x: 0, y: 0, mx:0, my:0 };

myDiv.onmousedown =({clientX:x,clientY:y})=> // on element mouse down
  {
  myDiv.classList.add('onMov');
  Object.assign( myDiv.mov, {x,y});  // get mouse position 
  myDiv.mov.x -= myDiv.mov.mx;       // prepare X delta
  myDiv.mov.y -= myDiv.mov.my;       // prepare Y delta
  }
window.onmouseup =_=>   // end of moving for any mouse up
  {
  myDiv.classList.remove('onMov')
  }
window.addEventListener('mousemove', ({clientX:x,clientY:y}) =>  
  {
  if (myDiv.classList.contains('onMov') && x > 0 && y > 0 )
    {
    myDiv.mov.mx = x - myDiv.mov.x;  // report mouse delta X
    myDiv.mov.my = y - myDiv.mov.y;  // report mouse delta y
    myDiv.style.setProperty('--movXY', `${myDiv.mov.mx}px, ${myDiv.mov.my}px`);
    }
  })
```

```css
#my-div {
  --movXY    : 0px,0px;
  background : dodgerblue;
  border     : 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  height     : 50px;
  width      : 50px;
  margin     : 30px;
  cursor     : grab;
  transform  : translate(var(--movXY));
  }
#my-div.onMov {
  cursor : grabbing;
  }
```

```html
<div id="my-div"></div>
```